# Get URL Parameters Using Javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, url, redirect, url-parameters

I have linked a site which redirects the browser to another server with a parameter "access_token"
e.g.

> http://somedomain.com/blank.html#access_token=sadf2342dsdfsd

How can I get this parameter from the URL before the page is redirected to the other server?

Comment: @GabrielSantos its 20% now :)

Comment: Good! To Stack Overflow become a better place, always accept the answers that solve your problems. This helps those looking for something similar to what you asked to solve their problems too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the address bar of a clients browser AFTER it has left your website?

That won't be possible unless you open the site in an `iframe` and then access the child frame with javascript.

You can do that easily by changing the target of your link, e.g.

Change this:

```
<a href="http://thewebsite.com/">Go to website</a>
```

To this:

```
<iframe name="tokenFrame" id="tokenFrame" width=1 height=1 frameborder=0> </iframe>
<a href="http://thewebsite.com/" target="tokenFrame">Don't go to website</a>
```

Then in javascript, after the page has changed to the one with the token:

```
var url = document.getElementById("tokenFrame").src
```

Or something similar to get the location e.g.

```
var frame = document.getElementById("tokenFrame");
var url = frame.top.location.href;
```

Or

```
var url = top.tokenFrame.location.href;
```

Finally parse the URL to get the value

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understand you question. Though I have som suggestions to the way of getting the access_token parameter from the URL.

Provided that you know the url, you can just explode the string and get the access_token.. It could look something like this:

```
echo end( explode('#', 'http://somedomain.com/blank.html#access_token=sadf2342dsdfsd'));
```

If your are directly at the site, you can use javascript to get the hash:

```
document.location.hash.substr(1)
```

Comment: so if I on http://somedomain.com/blank.html#access_token=sadf2342dsdfsd where I should paste this document.location.hash.substr(1) ? On my site from I redirected?

Comment: I don't understand where you are going with this, sorry. Is somedomain.com/blank.html#access_token=sadf2342dsdfsd your site, where you got access to the blank.html? If so, you should just put in the js-code in the blank.html-file. Perhaps with document.write:

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write (document.location.hash.substr(1));
</script>

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can grab the value of it like this

```
window.location.hash.replace('#access_token=','')
```